# Passing rails variables to .Rmd files for rendering R markdown

Tags: r, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails to render R markdown files to generate a Report. I have instance variables from Controller.

.Rmd file is in views folder. I am calling below in controller

```
File.read('path/to/file_name')
```

to read the .Rmd file. Below is a snippet of .Rmd file which is not working.

```
---
title: "Result Report"
params:
 selected_id: <%= "#{@result_id}" %>
 selected_gene: <%= "#{@gene}" %>
 selected_experiment: <%= "#{@experiment.id}" %>
```

Wondering how to achieve it. Stuck here for a while. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to do this. You have to read the File first and you can use gsub to replace the contents you want.

```
rmd_file = File.read("path/to/rmdFile")
rmd_file.gsub!('print_selected_gene', "\"#{@gene}\"")
```

This way you can replace the file anyways you want.

Comment: IMHO, this is a very hard to maintain solution. You are really exactly in the need of a templating engine and ERB is already in place in Rails.
You will have to gsub every variable name, and this will fail everytime someone changes a variable name.
They say : "If it ain't broken, don't fix it" but this will definitely break real soon.
My 2 cents :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to generated report in a browser, since you mention a controller.

Let's say the URL you have now to see an experiment is 
`/experiments/32/show`

You could use an extension like that 
`/experiments/32/show.report` to see the generated report

To achieve that you need three things

1. Change the controller

```
# app/controllers/experiments_controller.rb

class ExperimentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @experiment = Experiment.find(params[:id])
    @gene = ...
    @result_id = ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.report 
    end
  end
end
```

2. Register the `report` MIME type

As instructed [in the rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#restful-downloads) 
You need to add a line in the initializer `mime_types.rb` (create an empty file if you don't have any)

```
# config/initializers/mime_types.rb

Mime::Type.register "application/rtf", :report
```

3. Create the .report template using ERB

```
# app/views/experiments/show.report.erb

---
title: "Result Report"
params:
 selected_id: <%= @result_id %>
 selected_gene: <%= @gene %>
 selected_experiment: <%= @experiment.id %>
```

Comment: Thanks @babgyy. I found a simpler solution without needing to register MIME type. Appreciate your help in this.